install a new version of Gromacs
Hello everyone I'm a complete newbie on UBUNTU and infortmatic
I have this issue with Ubuntu. I tried to install a new version of Gromacs.
bioinfo@DESKTOP-VB6OCMK:~$ /Downloads
-bash: /Downloads: No such file or directory
bioinfo@DESKTOP-VB6OCMK:~$ Desktop
-bash: /Desktop: No such file or directory
same case for cd Users
How to fix this issue. Could someone please explain to me how to do this? Thanks

This question is similar to: When should I use the ~ (tilde) during command line navigation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Possibly you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? That is more like a server environment, and AFAIK doesn't create the typical desktop folders like ~/Downloads and ~/Desktop by default

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you using some guide to install Gromacs?
